# Python: why these two assignments cause different results?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I tried two different cases below. I hope the testcase is different from the testset. However, only by sencond method, the assertion returns warning.

```
In [95]: from random import shuffle

In [96]: testset = list(range(100)) 

In [97]: testcase = testset

In [98]: shuffle(testcase)

In [99]: assert testcase == testset

In [100]: testset2 = list(range(100))

In [101]: testcase2 = testset2[:]

In [102]: shuffle(testcase2)

In [103]: assert testcase2 == testset2
------------------------------------------------------ 
----------------
AssertionError                       Traceback (most 
recent call last)
<ipython-input-103-268525dbf253> in <module>()   
----> 1 assert testcase2 == testset2

AssertionError:
```

Comment: Be sure to read https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `testcase = testset`, `testcase` is *literally* the same list as `testset`. They are referring to the same list. If you do anything to one of them (like shuffle one), since both variables are pointing to the same list, both will be shuffled.

With `testcase2 = testset2[:]` however, `[:]` creates a copy of `testset2` and puts it in `testcase2`. They now point to different lists, so doing something to one will not effect the other. This is why `assert testcase2 == testset2` fails. One was shuffled. One was not.

Comment: So I guess is it something like 'pass by reference' and 'pass by value' ?

Comment: @RaymondQin Nothing is being passed here, so I don't think that would be relevant. The link chepner posted would likely clear up any confusion.